# opencv cvtColor assertion failed C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am getting an assertion error when I try to convert an input image to grayscale. I have seen 
lots of posts around the same issue but none seem to give a reason why it is erroring.
In the code below, input is NOT NULL and has been loaded from an image "test.jpg" on my drive
using imgRead.

```
Mat img_gray;
cvtColor(input, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Assertion Error:

OpenCV Automatic Number Plate Recognition
working with file: test
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

The code is taken from https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition/DetectRegions.cpp

check out line 72.

I have tried multiple pictures with no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Without the assertion message, how could we possibly guess what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That assertion message means that the image you passed in is not 3 or 4 channel.
E.g. if you pass in a one channel grayscale image it will fail.

try putting in

std::cerr << "image chans : " << image.channels() << std::endl;

immediately before `cvtColor()`. I am sure that it won't output 3 or 4.

Comment: I assumed only grey scale images would have a single channel.